# 'heroku run bash' gives ECONNREFUSED 52.3.44.61:5000

Tags: django, postgresql, bash, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django project and trying to create tables and superuser.

```
(env) D:\CRM>heroku run bash
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.1.
Running bash on ⬢ quiet-waters-22939... done
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 52.3.44.61:5000
```

My PostgreSQL settings are:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

Is the above error due to the fact that the port number in the `postgresql = 5432` and the error is on port number 5000?
If yes, then do I need to change the port number or is it something else?

Other similar errors:

```
(env) D:\CRM>heroku pg:psql             
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.1.
--> Connecting to postgresql-clean-14965
psql: error: connection to server at "ec2-54-157-79-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (54.157.79.121), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?  
 !    psql exited with code 2
```

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.1.
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ quiet-waters-22939... done
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.156.98.218:5000
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: but even heroku pg:psql is throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the error but i got around it by using the console from Heroku Dashboard instead of using my terminal .